# Joomla jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, joomla

on my website http: //******.com/, when I upgrade to php 7 it gives me the error of Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined when it is defined at the beginning of my index.php

The strange thing is that with version 5 of php everything is correct. What can be the failure?

```
$jquery = '';
jimport('joomla.version');
$version = new JVersion();
if(version_compare($version->getShortVersion(), '3.0', '>=')){
    JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
} else {
    JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
    JFactory::getDocument()->addScript($this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/js/jq.min.js');
}
```

Then inside of html of the index.php any jQuery code tells me that it is not defined. Why can it be?

Thank you!!

Comment: The first two steps you can take are: #1 Look in the output HTML source to see if the JQuery library is included; and #2 Open your browser's code debugger, look at the network activity, and see if the JQuery libraries are loaded.

Comment: The website is http://lcbikesmartorell.com/

the browser debugger tells me that it is not defined when I defined a block of php code that introduced the beginning of index.html before the html and head

Comment: The JQuery library is not being included in the head of your HTML document. You would expect to see something like `<script src="jquery-3.x.x.js"></script>` (depending on location of your library) there. Since your post makes it clear that Joomla should have been generating this, I have no idea why it doesn't (I don't have much experience of Joomla I'm afraid).

Comment: @FelipeJiménezPrieto When you want to receive support from individuals with Joomla-specific expertise, please post your questions on [Joomla Stack Exchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: `<script src="js/jq.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is in fact being written in the source code.  This means that your conditional is going to the `else` block.  If you want to load the jquery with `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` put that in your `else` block.  Let us know how this goes.

Comment: What version are you actually on? and why aren't you upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your core joomla jQuery, install this plugin [jQuery easy](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jquery-easy/)

in plugin configurations you can change core joomla jQuery